# What's the best way to customize the Wordpress Menu Page (in admin)

Tags: menus

Helo,

I would like to restyle/reorganize my Admin Menu Page (wp-admin/nav-menus.php).

What's the best way of doing this? Can I just edit the page directly?

Comment: If you expand the details of your question, then perhaps there is a more acceptable solution

Comment: Basically I would like to restyle the page, for example : I would like to remove the ability to create multiple menu, and just have 1 fixed one instead.

Comment: Also allow to drag and drop page from the Pages to Menu

Comment: As wikicms said, expand the details of your question. You can edit it after posting. Although you're adding details in the comments, they're better fit in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Editing the the file is not a good idea, it'll be replaced next time you update your wp installation, why don't you just enqueue a new css file and overwrite what you want to change, a lot can be accomplished with css without changing the markup.

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    wp_register_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media );
    wp_enqueue_style( $handle );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are a lots of plugins to modify the wp admin

have a look at:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ag-custom-admin/

or

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fluency-admin/